# How to make a Matrix Class in smalltalk Visual Works?

Tags: matrix, smalltalk, pharo, tic-tac-toe, visualworks

I am new to smalltalk and trying to make a simple TicTacToe game, I want my model class to be a matrix but I can't find a way to do it on Visual Works. I've been following this tutorial : http://nerdysermons.blogspot.fr/2012/03/tictactoe-game-in-pharo-smalltalk.html , it works just fine with Pharo but I'm having trouble with the Matrix type and also the simplebuttonmorph. Can anyone please explain the syntax/packages/libraries between Pharo and VisualWorks? Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a suggestion - there are many ways to implement matrices.

1. Define a class as a subclass of Object with instance variables for cells, numberOfRows and numberOfColumns.
2. Create a class method to initialize the matrix given the number of rows and number of columns - make the cells an array of size rows * columns
3. Create methods like at:at: and at:at:put: which calculate an index into the cells array as follows:

> ```
> cellNumberAt: row at: column
>    ^(row - 1) * numberOfColumns + column
>
> at: row at: column put: value
>    cells at: (self cellNumberAt: row at: column) put: value
>
> at: row at: column
>    ^cells at: (self cellNumberAt: row at: column)
>
> rowAt: rowNumber
>    | row |
>    row := OrderedCollection new.
>    1 to: numberOfColumns do: [:columnNumber |
>       row add: (self at: rowNumber at: columnNumber)].
>    ^row
>
> columnAt: columnNumber
>    | column |
>    column := OrderedCollection new.
>    1 to: numberOfRows do: [:rowNumber |
>       column add: (self at: rowNumber at: columnNumber)].
>    ^column
> ```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Perhaps, then, you could mark the question as answered.  I'm glad you got the answer you're looking for.